# Can't access internet through wirtual hotspot

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, windows, wifi-hotspot

I have rooted  phone with Android 4.0 and laptop with Windows 8.
I have made wirtual hotspot with:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow name=** key=**
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Than I shared my default connection to newly created, phone have found this network, but couldn't connect to it (claimed 'avoided poor internet connection'). 
After googling around I figured out that I should set static IP, and phone finally connected to network, but without working internet. I have absolutely no idea what to do next.

Here is output of ipconfig /all: (PC internet connection - `Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2`; hotspot connection - `Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12`) 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5925983/

Android device configuration:

```
IP - 169.254.179.101
Gateway - 169.254.179.10
Network prefix length - 16
DNS 1 - 169.254.179.10
DNS 2 - 8.8.4.4
```

UPD: Wifi analyser on Android side shows

```
Server IP: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about Windows than Android.

Comment: @roxan Actually, I am pretty sure that the problem lies in wrong configuration of static IP on Android side, so I suppose, it is not.

Comment: I'd say that this is okay here. Did you look through the other [tag:wifi-hotspot] questions we have here?

Comment: Just for clarification: Is the created hotspot by any chance an ad-hoc network -- or is it truly "infrastructure" mode? Because if it's ad-hoc, it's not supported out-of-the-box by Android.

Comment: Are you sure the Windows box is set up to act as a router? That's not the usual configuration, so if you haven't done anything to enable that on your laptop, you won't be able to access its internet connection from other devices via W-Fi.

Comment: @Kriattiffer IMHO, if you didn't know how to put static IP in Android then it would have been Android question.   To figure out the correct static IP you need to do it in your Windows computer. To fix anything like incorrect routing settings or Wi-Fi properties you've to do it in Windows. You shared Internet doesn't work on Android phone and won't work in any other device until you fix it in Windows computer.

Comment: @AlEverett have read'em all (both here and on SuperUser), there are some relevant things, but nothing to solve this problem.

Comment: @Izzy I suppose that I if created AP, it couldn't be ad-hoc, could it?

Comment: @Dan Honestly, I don't understand. What shoud be enabled on laptop in this case?

Comment: @Kriattiffer there are a lot of solutions for Windows creating ad-hoc "hotspots". I do not say you did, I just wanted to definitly rule that out. Otherwise we work on symptoms never reaching anywhere if it turns out it was ad-hoc.